# Connecting Intellij IDEA DB Navigator Plugin to Oracle DB connection

Tags: java, oracle, docker, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have my Oracle 12C installed in docker and it run in port 1521.
This is the command i used to run my oracle image

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 1521:1521 -v ~/oracle_data/:/u01/app/oracle truevoly/oracle-12c
```

I am able to connect Oracle Database with Oracle Sql Developer with the following configuration.
[image]

I am using Intellij community Edition.I am trying to connect with Oracle Database using DB Navigator Plugin , but when i provide the same Credentials as earlier, I am getting the error as "Cannot Connect to Database"[image]

Can someone suggest what needs to be fixed to make it connected.

Comment: Are you able to connect to anythig else from IntlliJ? Check firewall maybe it's blocking intelliJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection Timeout was set to 5 seconds , whereas incerasing the timeout has fixed the issue